# Save a filename, given by command-line, in a dynamically generated String

Tags: c, string, malloc

I am writing a program that gets a filepath-name from the command-line and then proceeds to open the file. My question is: Is it possible to create a string, the moment the user gives the input, that would be exactly the size needed for the filepath to fit into it? If not, what would be the ideal size for the non-dynamical char array I would have to use?

I just want to get rid of the hard-coded string size:

```
char filename[100];
scanf(" %s", filename);
```

It comes with so many problems.

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you are doing now, or what you tried ?

Comment: Is the full path given on the command line, or should it be modified later by user input? It's not clear to me. Also, there should be a PATH_MAX (or possibly MAX_PATH, on older systems) define if you include `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Well i guess, giving it from commandline as an argument and giving it through scanf shouldnt make a difference. I was planning on implementing both.

Comment: Well if it's from the command line, then you have it fight there and don't need to allocate memory for it unless you modify it later. Otherwise it's either Blagovests solution or a fixed-size `char`-array.

Comment: If you're using a system that supports is, try canonicalize_file_name(3).  This is a gnu extension of realpath that allocates space for a path.

Comment: won't "int main (int argc, char **argv){" automatically do this job for you? What i mean is if you pass the output file name along with the executable via command line then argv[1] will be automatically allocated the size of the output file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the C standard the FILENAME_MAX macro (defined in stdio.h) specifies either the maximum or recommended length of file names (quote: `222) If the implementation imposes no practical limit on the length of file name strings, the value of FILENAME_MAX should instead be the recommended size of an array intended to hold a file name string.`). I'd say, find out the filename length limits of your target OS.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `scanf` with the `%as` format specifier. It should allocate the buffer for you, relieving you about worrying what size to specify for the buffer:

```
char *buf;
scanf("%as", &buf);
```

From the [Linux manual](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

> An optional 'a' character.  This is used with string conversions, and
>   relieves the caller of the need to allocate a corresponding buffer to
>   hold the input: instead, scanf() allocates a buffer of sufficient
>   size, and assigns the address of this buffer to the corresponding
>   pointer argument, which should be a pointer to a char * variable (this
>   variable does not need to be initialized before the call).  The caller
>   should subsequently free(3) this buffer when it is no longer required.
>   This is a GNU extension; C99 employs the 'a' character as a conversion
>   specifier (and it can also be used as such in the GNU implementation).

Comment: so this cannot be used in ansi c ?